# Adding mulitple rows with same information on a few columns

Tags: list

I am trying to set up a form in sharepoint. Staff will add lab orders to the form where  about 5 values will be initially entered ( name, designation, project etc.)  (Part A)
then they will add  10 rows of data for each item ordered where each row will have a unique ID with say 7 columns each.  ( say patient sample id for each sample collected).  (Part B)

when they submit the  form, this data is stored as 10 rows, where the first  5 column values are taken from the Part A ( and repeated for all 10 rows)  and the next 7 columns are taken from from B .

result on submission
the list will have additional 10 tows  with 12 columns each , each row has a system generated unique id

How to set up this form on sharepoint ? there will be many samples entered each time and we do not want the first 5 column values to be entered each time.

Also, is it possible to have this set up sent by outlook email.

saras

Answer (score 0):

Create Repeating Table. For each field, the default value might be the: max(double click to insert field).